# 'PdfTextExtractor' does not contain definition for 'GetTextFromPage'

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

'PdfTextExtractor' does not contain definition for 'GetTextFromPage', it throws [Compiler Error CS0117](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0117?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0117))

This is my code, which I have coppied just to check how does iText7 work:

```
using System;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener;

namespace PdfParser
{
    public static class PdfTextExtractor
    {
        public static void ExtractTextFromPDF(string filePath)
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                // the line below throws the exception
                string pageContent = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page), strategy);
            }

            pdfDoc.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using iTextCsharp, but there was writen that iText7 is a new version.

I am working on "Console Application", maybe this is the problem? Should I use another framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your class is also called `PdfTextExtractor`. Please rename your static class and the issue will be solved.

For future issues, you can jump to the reference (via F12 or similar, depending on your IDE/Shorctus) and check where it directs you.